# что не так в makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

здравствуйте, есть такой makefile:

```
СC= g++
CFLAGS= -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -I.
LIBS=   -lboost_system \
        -lpthread

TARGET= targ
OBJECTS= main.o \
         file1.o


all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  main.cpp 

file1.o : connects.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  connects.cpp
```

вылетает ошибка main.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEaSEPKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21»
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
Makefile:15: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «targ»

однако если вручную все сделать g++  -o targ main.o file1.o -lboost_system -lpthread , то все отлично проскакивает... в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: См CFLAGS. При ручном вызове они не используются.

Comment: не, в итоговой цели CFLAGS тоже не используются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле проблема в том что у вас в качестве компилятора будет использоваться gcc (cc), а не g++ (у меня получилось так), make почему то проигнорировал `CC = g++` (чтобы быть уверенным, что у вас также приложите полный вывод make). Или добавьте в LIBS `-lstdc++`, или, что правильно, для С++ используйте CXX вместо СС и CXXFLAGS вместо CFLAGS, собственно их для того и придумали, чтобы с C++ кодом работать.

**P.S.** А как у вас вообще дошло до линковки, у меня без правки цели `file1.o` падало, так как в ней создавался файл `connects.o`, а не `file1.o`.